# Delete old records from table and backup those records in new backup table before date

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a MYSQL table that needs to backup old records before 01 Jan 2021, to the new backup table. And delete old records before 01 Jan 2021 from the original table. The original table has a created_on column to filter the date. How can I do this operation?

Comment: *How can I create a single query for this?* Noway. Except this single query is `CALL` to SP which performs needed action. But I'd recommend not actual/archive tables but partitioning.

Comment: These are two different operations. This cannot be resolved in one query. Next.

Comment: If it needs two operations, can you please describe each one of those @Strawberry

Comment: If you have a different question, I suggest you amend or delete this one accordingly

Comment: Of course therre exists a method to perform this everything "by one query". The action of another query may be performed by AFTER DELETE trigger. But this is not reasonable, and the process will be slow.

Comment: my table as too many records, so it slows down the entire page when called. so I just want to delete old record and backup those record in new backup table and delete those old records before '2021-01-01 00:00:00' from original table

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). OP states that "Too many records, so it slows down the entire page", and wants to delete and back up old data, hoping that it will improve apps performance. It this is the case, perhaps the solution is not delete old data, but proper indexing on tables and server fine tuning.

Comment: [XY Problem on meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the quicker way is to do this:

1. Create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE original_table;
```

2. Insert data from 01 Jan 2021 into new table. Depending on the data, this might be much quicker than inserting old data into new table. Simply because if the old data is from year 2001, just imagine how many rows it has compared to a half year of 2021 data:

```
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM original_table WHERE created_on >= '2021-01-01';
```

3. Rename old and new tables:

```
RENAME TABLE original_table TO old_table1;
RENAME TABLE new_table TO original_table;
```

4. Check if all year `2021` data exists in the new table. Once confirmed, you can proceed to delete `2021` data from the old table OR remain it there; that's up to you.